# How to calculate significance for pairwise Fst (fixation index)?

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, biostatistics, fishers-exact-test

I have 6 populations of fishes and 6 values of Fst (Fixation Index: A measure of population differentiation due to genetic structure) associated with each of these. I want to do a pairwise comparison of the 6 populations to check if they are really different from each other or not (significance)

I am unsure on what test I can use to proceed with the analysis. [Some papers] (Table 3)[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19734259) that I have read claim that they have used a Fishers Exact Test. However, given that Fishers Exact test is applicable only to a 2x2 or greater matrix, I am not sure if that is the right the way to proceed.